# How to make CircleCI use a specific Gradle version?

Tags: android, gradle, circleci

It's still using 2.14.1 while I wanted 3.3 in my case:
despite the following circle.yml:

```
machine:
  environment:
    PATH: "~/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/gradle-3.3/bin:$PATH"
    TERM: "dumb"
    ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT: "10"
    GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8

dependencies:
  pre:
    # Install Android stuffs
    - wget "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip"; unzip gradle-3.3-bin.zip
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tool
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-25
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-25.0.2
test:
  override:
    # start the emulator
    - emulator -avd circleci-android19 -no-audio -no-window:
        background: true
        parallel: true
    # wait for it to have booted
    - circle-android wait-for-boot
    # unlock the emulator screen
    - sleep 30
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Wrong version is likely the version why `gradle dependencies` is failing for me here:
[image]

Comment: Not a gradle person but I found this article. Seems to imply it might be an issue with your Task wrapper. http://blog.originate.com/blog/2015/03/22/android-and-ci-and-gradle-a-how-to/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `yourProject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties"`, you can define `gradle` version. Like this:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4-all.zip` 
`

### Update

I do not think it's necessary to `wget "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip"` because when the CI invokes `./gradlew`, it will download gradle automatically.